# How to check in Linux if my python script opens an HTTP connection

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I'm looking for some command/tool that will show me that my python script opens a connection with a server and receiving data.

here is an example python script if it's going to help:

```
import requests
r = requests.post('https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json',data={'track':'justinbieber'},auth=('user','pass'),headers={'Connection':'close'},stream=True)
```

Comment: Why not just trying to return anything?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+port+sniffer

Comment: IMO you can't do it offline, use tshark.

Comment: try "lsof -i", to show all the connected connection with process name, port, host.

Comment: Thank to everybody, I think rakib answered my question : lsof -i | grep python

Comment: tshark is  a good choice also

Comment: netstat -taupe would be my favorite